# how to send scheduled push notifications to flutter app

Tags: flutter, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, android-notifications

I have flutter app which data ,I will get through api and there list of appointments data with that data I need to remind user by notification so I tried  local notification, background fetch in flutter but not working as expected

Any other proper way to remind notification before appointment time like push notification and i'm using backend C# for writing api

Comment: what is the problem with local notification?

Comment: in local notification , when user not using continuously app  not able to schedule the notification and also show push notification  some other functionality in app

Answer (score 0):

Look into https://github.com/winsw/winsw/releases

A wrapper executable that can run any executable as a Windows service.